# Ion tabs change the content not the all page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this html :

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="8">
            <ion-tabs>
                <ion-tab-bar slot="top">
                    <ion-tab-button tab="trend">
                        <ion-label>Trending</ion-label>
                    </ion-tab-button>

                    <ion-tab-button tab="not-trend">
                        <ion-label>Not Trend</ion-label>
                    </ion-tab-button>
                </ion-tab-bar>
            </ion-tabs>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="4">Hi</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
<div class="content"></div>
</ion-content>
```

When I access : `/campaigns` I have this page with 2 tabs. Now I want to change only the content of div `<div class="content"></div>` and not to create a dedicated page for each tab. Is possible to do that without dedicated route for each tab ? Thx in advance

Comment: You seem like you'd benefit from moving away from ion-tabs and using ion-segment
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment

Answer (score 1):

This is not what `ion-tabs` is meant to do. This is what `ion-segment` is for https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment

> Their functionality is similar to tabs, where selecting one will deselect all others. Segments are useful for toggling between different views inside of the content. Tabs should be used instead of a segment when clicking on a control should navigate between pages.